# Convert tbl to dataframes for multiple datasets in R

Tags: r

I have got the list of datasets (20) in tbl formats. Is there a way to convert all of them to dataframes in single command in R? Please guide me

Comment: `lapply(tibble_list, data.frame)` ?

Answer (score 0):

You could convert list of tibbles into dataframe by using `lapply`

```
dataframe_list <- lapply(tibble_list, data.frame)
#OR
#lapply(tibble_list, as.data.frame)
#purrr::map(tibble_list, data.frame)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
dataframe_list <- lapply(tibble_list, as.data.frame)
```

Or with `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
map(tibble_list, as.data.frame)
```